# Multiple Criteria Lookup in Parent List

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, workflow-lookup

I have a list of projects (Project List) and another list of periodic status updates (Status Update List) related to each project (one-to-many).  I need a lookup column in the Project List that displays the date of the last status update connected to the given Project (the most recent date in the Created field in the Status Update List).

Using Sharepoint 2010. Any ideas would be appreciated.